# IF AND MATCH OR

Tags: excel

I've been wracking my brain for a while on this and can't seem to get it right.

So I have a large set of data that needs to be checked for matches What I am trying to get is:
I have an identifying number and I have a code I need to match. 
So 1st - Look for the code in header for a match on Open Tasks AND look for a match for identifying number in Open Tasks. If this is the case, then matched.

The 2nd - Look for the code in header for a match on Completed Tasks AND look for a match for identifying number in Completed Tasks. If this is the case, then matched.

If EITHER of the statements is true, then Matched.

Below is what I attempted to use to make it work.

```
=IF(OR(AND(MATCH(CK$1, 'Completed Tasks'!$B:$B, 0), MATCH($A2, 'Completed Tasks'!$A:$A, 0)), AND(MATCH(CK$1,'Open Tasks'!$A:$A,0),MATCH($A2,'Open Tasks'!$N:$N,0))), "Matched", "Not Matched")
```

I even broke it down into these two separate formulas, which both separately give me what I'm looking for.

```
=IF(AND(MATCH(CK$1, 'Completed Tasks'!$B:$B, 0), MATCH($A2, 'Completed Tasks'!$A:$A, 0)), "Matched", "Not Matched)

=IF(AND(MATCH(CK$1,'Open Tasks'!$A:$A,0),MATCH($A2,'Open Tasks'!$N:$N,0)),"Matched","Not Matched")
```

When I try to combine though, I fail. Pretty sure I'm messing up parenthesis somewhere.

Comment: Are the identifying number code intended to be on the same row in either 'Open Tasks' or 'Completed Tasks'?

Comment: No, they are not. The data sources have them in two different areas

Comment: Then the `COUNTIF` solution provided below seems your best bet. If they were supposed to be in the same row then a `COUNTIFS` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `MATCH` gives an `#N/A` error when there is no match, it's a little difficult to use `MATCH` here - try multiplying two COUNTIFS, if they are both >0 then the result of the multiplication will be >0 too, e.g.

`=IF(OR(COUNTIF(Completed Tasks'!$B:$B,CK$1)*COUNTIF(Completed Tasks'!$A:$A,$A2),COUNTIF('Open Tasks'!$A:$A,CK$1)*COUNTIF('Open Tasks'!$N:$N,$A2))"Matched","Not Matched")`

Answer (score 0):

=IF(AND(MATCH(CK$1, 'Completed Tasks'!$B:$B, 0), MATCH($A2, 'Completed Tasks'!$A:$A, 0)), "Matched",IF(AND(MATCH(CK$1,'Open Tasks'!$A:$A,0),MATCH($A2,'Open Tasks'!$N:$N,0)), "Matched","Not Matched"))

Try it this way and see if it works.

Comment: YOU may need to break down the if na statements to each part.

Comment: I actually had an IFError before it. The NA's aren't what's tripping me up though.  As I'm running it, I can see that it's not getting the data back to me correctly. It's only catching if BOTH statements are true. Which is not what I want. I've looked through it many times and I feel like I have the right order, but I'm not getting the right answer

Comment: OK then try XOR

Comment: XOR will give me a false if both are true though. The issue I'm running into is that the formula I put in my original post should be resulting in a lot more "Matched" It's only turning up the cases where both are true though. I want it to show if 1 is true OR if both are true. It's only giving me if BOTH are true currently.  That is what I can't figure out.  Where did I go wrong in my formula there?

Comment: This should work. I think this way or Not Xor will give you the same truth table.

Comment: Is really close. It gave me all the one's I wanted to see for the 1st function. But the 2nd part is still missing some info. From the looks of it, the function you gave identified all the 1st formula as matched and then all the BOTH matches. But it still excluded the 2nd part's individual matches.

Comment: so you are wanting 4 individual matches? if any of the 4 match to trigger true?